# Link as a Dropdown item and with pre-defined color

Tags: javascript, tinymce

[image]

I would like to have Link and Unlink as an option in a Dropdown Menu and with a pre-defined color (blue). So much so that all hyperlinks text would have the blue color. Anyone knows how to do it?

See the code below, I added link in block_format so I can see the work "link" in a dropdown, but how can I set the default color and open the link dialog box when someone click on "Link" item?

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#" + id,
        theme : "modern",
        width: 660,
        height: 280,
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        plugins: "paste,link,textcolor",
        block_formats: "Paragraph=p;Header 1=h1;Header 2=h2;Header 3=h3; link",
        toolbar: [
            "formatselect forecolor | undo redo | link unlink",
            "bold italic underline | bullist numlist | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify"
        ],
        setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('init', function(e){
                tinymce.get(id).setContent($scope.params.content);
            });
            editor.on('change',function(e){
                $scope.params.content = escapeIllegalCharacters(tinymce.get(id).getContent());
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please what you have done and also provide the code too

Comment: Yeah, use CSS for that.